# Fetch last row first in displayed array without using SELECT command?

Tags: php, database, foreach

I have used foreach loop to display the rows in myphp database, however I would now like to display this in DESC order (display last row first) however research tells me not to use the SELECT command in arrays? is there another way? Many thanks.

index.php:

```
<?php 
include("app/database/db.php");

$posts = selectAll('posts', ['published' => 1]);
?>


<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

    <div class="post">
      <div class="col-lg-6">

      <!-- HEADLINE -->
      <h1><strong><a href="/single_page_main.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></strong></h1>
      
      <!-- TEXT BODY -->
      <!-- <h4></?php echo $post['body']; ?></h4> displays the full body -->
      <h4 class="mainbody"><?php echo html_entity_decode(substr($post['body'], 0, 100) . '...'); ?></h4> 
      <!-- IMAGE -->
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="<?php echo '/assets/images/' , $post['image']; ?>" style="width: 550px; height:      350px; object-fit: cover;">
      </div>

    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

db.php file:

```
<?php

function selectAll($table, $conditions = []) {

  global $conn;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
  if (empty($conditions)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $records;
  } else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
      if ($i === 0) {
        $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
      } else {
        $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?";
      }
      $i++;
    }


    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
    $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $records;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: You want to display it the other way around always, or just on a button press after you've first displayed it this way around? If it always needs to be the other sequence, add DESC on the end of the query. If you can't do that, instead of `foreach()` through the returned array, you could use a `for` loop using the `count()` function to see how many elements there are - something like `for ($i=count($posts)-1; $i >=0; $i++) { ` followed by `$post = $posts[$i];` inside the loop. If you want to re-order it after display, I think that would be a JavaScript thing,

Comment: Hi @droopsnoot, I want to display it in reverse always. Yeh great point, i'll try the for loop way you've mentioned as well. Thanks!